# PushModalAsync page change animation is laggy

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to make a simple transition between two pages, but whenever I'm using `PushModalAsync`, I experience a lot of frame loss.

I have tested this on multiple phones and the problem persists on a Samsung Galaxy A3(2016) and a Samsung Galaxy A5(2016), but not on a Huawei P9 Lite. As a note, these three phones do not have a huge spec difference between them.

Is there any way that I can make the transition smooth or not show the animation at all?

I'm using the following code:

```
var newPage = new NewPage();
await PushModalAsync(newPage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run in background...

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
var newPage = new NewPage();
return newPage;
}).ContinueWith(tnp=>{PushModalAsync(tnp.Result);});
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Well, I guess it's an issue with the GPU of the older devices which has a difficult time rendering the animations without frame loss. Furthermore, I guess it is difficult to optimise the `PushModalAsync` code beyond its current state.

What you could do is to use the `PushModalAsync(Page, bool)` [overload](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.PushModalAsync/p/Xamarin.Forms.Page/System.Boolean/). Simply use `false` to avoid the `page` to be animated. This will avoid the additional load on the GPU of the animation. Conclusively, you *should* no longer experience the frame loss.